# Regex need some assistance

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have a number and I want to make sure the first 7 chars are letters and the next char is a digit.

so far I have this that tests for all chars in a string:

```
function HasNumbers(value) {
return /[0-9]/.test(value);

}
```

Comment: [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) doesn't test all chars of the argument, but just whether the regex matches any subsequence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{7}[0-9]/
```

- `^` - the beginning of the string
- `[a-zA-Z]{7}` - 7 consecutive letters, any case
- `[0-9]` - a number

Comment: Too fast for us :-) I think you can just add a `$` sign at the end nevertheless...

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie, The OP didn't specify that the string ended after the digit. The end anchor can be added if that is the intention, but I don't know if it is.

Answer (score 1):

You could;

```
   /^[A-Z]{7}\d{1}$/i.test( ... );
```

Comment: The `^` and `$` are *start* and *end-of-line* anchors respectively; http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html